# How to get Windows.Point from Lat/Long

Tags: vb.net, bing-maps

I am using the Bing Map Control for wpf on Windows 10.  Given a Lat/Long location I need to get the Windows.Point value for that location.  It should be relative to the map itself, namely, the upperleft corner (0,0).  I use the Map.ViewportPointToLocation to go from a mouse location to the corresponding Lat/Long.  Now I need the inverse function; I have not been able to find anything via web searches.

Comment: LocationToViewportPoint().  That was a bit too obvious, expand the question to show your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the maps `TryLocationToViewportPoint` or `LocationToViewportPoint` methods.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/bing/wpf-control/hh709346(v=msdn.10)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/bing/wpf-control/hh709336(v=msdn.10)

Comment: Boy, my google skills sure came up a cropper on this one.  Thanks.

Comment: The docs are archived, so they may have a low SEO index.